# Center, crop, fit video background (in iframe) to parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, video, iframe

Given the following markup:

```
<div class="viewport">
    <iframe src="youtube.com/blabla"></iframe>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
.viewport {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And given the following facts:

- The video that plays within the iframe will have an aspect ratio of 16:9

**Is it possible to write a script that stretches the iframe to a size greater than the parent so that the iframe overflows, hiding the black bars?** (yes I know it will also crop part of the video but that's ok)

Here's two examples that the script must solve:

[image: wide]
[image: tall]

In the first image, the black bars are on the left and right. To fix it, the script would stretch the iframe wider and taller, thus stretching the video within in, until the black bars are gone. We'd lose the top and bottom of the video but that's ok. In the second image, the black bars are on the top and bottom, and we'd need to stretch it and lose the sides of the video.

Here is my annotated attempt to do it, but unfortunately, the code does't cover all cases. Once the aspect ratio of my viewport goes above ~2.1, the black bars come back. Feel free to scrap my script.

```
    var block = $('.viewport');
    var block_h = block.outerHeight();
    var block_w = block.outerWidth();

    var ratio = block_w / block_h;

    // If viewport is landscape (black bars on left/right)
    if( ratio >= 1.77777778 ) {
        var video_w = (block_h * 16) / 9; // Get width of video within iframe
        var total_black_bar_w = block_w - video_w; // Black bar total width
        var new_iframe_w = (block_w + total_black_bar_w); // New width of the iframe needed to stretch the video wide enough to hide the black bars
        var adjustment_percentage = new_iframe_w / block_w; // If we adjusted the width by 10% for example, then we also need to apply that percentage to the height

        var new_iframe_h = (block_h * adjustment_percentage) + 30;

        var pull_left = total_black_bar_w / 2; // how far to pull left to center the iframe outside of the parent container
        var pull_top = (new_iframe_h - block_h) / 2; // same for top
    }
    // Portrait viewport (black bars on top/bottom)
    else {
        var video_h = (block_w * 9) / 16;
        var total_black_bar_h = block_h - video_h;
        var new_iframe_h = (block_h + total_black_bar_h);
        var adjustment_percentage = new_iframe_h / block_h;

        var new_iframe_w = (block_w * adjustment_percentage) + 30;

        var pull_left = total_black_bar_w / 2;
        var pull_top = (new_iframe_h - block_h) / 2;
    }

    block.find('iframe').css({
        'width': new_iframe_w,
        'height': new_iframe_h,
        'left': '-' + pull_left + 'px',
        'top': '-' + pull_top + 'px'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually simpler than your code.

Always keep the ratio of the iframe, but just resize (*scale in reality*) the whole thing accordingly to fill the viewport.

Use css positioning / transform to center it.

Here is an example with smaller viewport (*with red border*) so you can see it in action.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var viewport = $('.viewport'),
    frame = viewport.find('iframe'),
    frameRatio = 16 / 9;

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var width = viewport.outerWidth(),
      height = viewport.outerHeight(),
      ratio = width / height,
      targetWidth = width,
      targetHeight = height;

    if (ratio > frameRatio) {
      // viewport is wider than video
      // correct the height
      targetHeight = width / frameRatio;
    } else {
      // viewport is taller than video
      // correct the width
      targetWidth = height * frameRatio;
    }

    frame.css({
      width: targetWidth,
      height: targetHeight
    });
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
.viewport {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10% 25%;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="viewport">
  <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1La4QzGeaaQ?autoplay=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

See it at http://jsfiddle.net/agrxtwn7/embedded/ (*go to Result*) because it seems that SO stops the youtube embed from playing

Comment: Wow it works! I had to remove the z-index: -1 because of my particular layout but apart from that it's perfect. Much thanks

Comment: @Brian, yes i put the -1 so you could see the border of the viewport.